# SQL Server: String insertion by position

Tags: sql-server, string, common-table-expression

I want to insert a set of values into a given string at specified positions. I couldn't find an existing solution for this so I created the following query which does so. I am wondering if there is a way to simplify it, especially the portion which queries the cte and creates the NewString. Also, is there a way to construct the cte recursion without involving the ID column? The ID (and the rest) seems to work fine, just wondering if it could be tweaked to make it more organic/elegant or if there is a better solution overall. The different groups are really only for testing purposes; each group corresponds to a possible insertion position scenario. Thus, there will not be groups involved when I use it.

```
declare
    @String varchar(200),
    @StringLen int,
    @GroupID int,
    @PositionMax int

declare @Chars table (
    ID int identity,
    GroupID int,
    Position int,
    Value varchar(20)
    )

select
    @String = 'abcde',
    @StringLen = len(@String),
    @GroupID = 1

--Affix
--[P]refix
--[I]nfix
--[S]uffix

insert @Chars
select
    GroupID,
    Position,
    Value
from (
    values
        (1, 0, 'X'),    --P
        (2, 2, 'Y'),    --I
        (3, 5, 'Z'),    --S
        (4, 0, 'X'),    --P
        (4, 2, 'Y'),    --I
        (5, 2, 'Y'),    --I
        (5, 5, 'Z'),    --S
        (6, 0, 'X'),    --P
        (6, 5, 'Z'),    --S
        (7, 0, 'X'),    --P
        (7, 2, 'Y'),    --I
        (7, 5, 'Z'),    --S
        (8, 2, 'Y1'),   --I
        (8, 4, 'Y2'),   --I
        (9, 0, 'X'),    --P
        (9, 2, 'Y1'),   --I
        (9, 4, 'Y2'),   --I
        (10, 2, 'Y1'),  --I
        (10, 4, 'Y2'),  --I
        (10, 5, 'Z'),   --S
        (11, 0, 'X'),   --P
        (11, 2, 'Y1'),  --I
        (11, 4, 'Y2'),  --I
        (11, 5, 'Z')    --S
    ) as T(GroupID, Position, Value)
order by GroupID, Position

;with cte (
    ID,
    GroupID,
    LeftString,
    Value,
    RightString,
    Position
    ) as (
    select
        ID,
        GroupID,
        LeftString,
        Value,
        RightString,
        Position
    from (
        select
            row_number() over (partition by GroupID order by ID) as RowNumber,
            ID,
            GroupID,
            cast(left(@String, Position) as varchar(200)) as LeftString,
            Value,
            cast(right(@String, @StringLen - Position) as varchar(200)) as RightString,
            Position
        from @Chars
        ) as C
    where RowNumber = 1
    union all
    select
        vc.ID,
        vc.GroupID,
        cast(left(RightString, vc.Position - cte.Position) as varchar(200)) as LeftString,
        vc.Value,
        cast(right(RightString, @StringLen - vc.Position) as varchar(200)) as RightString,
        vc.Position
    from @Chars vc
    join cte cte
        on cte.GroupID = vc.GroupID
            and cte.ID + 1 = vc.ID
    )
    select
        GroupID,
        case
            when LSLenSumMax < @StringLen
                then NewString + RightString
            else NewString
        end as NewString
    from (
        select
            GroupID,
            max(LSLenSum) as LSLenSumMax,
            RightString,
            stuff((
                select
                    LeftString + Value
                from cte cte
                where cte.GroupID = cteLR.GroupID
                for xml path(''), type
                ).value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 0, '') as NewString
        from (
            select
                GroupID,
                (select sum(len(LeftString)) from cte cteL where cteL.groupID = cte.groupID) as LSLenSum,
                (select top 1 RightString from cte cteR where cteR.groupID = cte.groupID order by cteR.ID desc) as RightString
            from cte cte
            ) as cteLR
            group by
                GroupID,
                RightString
            ) as C
    order by GroupID
```

Comment: I don't know a way, but a couple of days ago I found a really cool article about n-Grams that might be of some help: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom 
aggregate function... Or try this: A recursive scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPrefixTo (@GroupID INT, @Position INT, @String CHAR(200))
RETURNS Char(200)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str CHAR(200) = NULL
    DECLARE @beforePosition INT = 0
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Chars WHERE GroupID = @GroupID AND Position < @Position) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @beforePosition = MAX(Position) FROM chars WHERE GroupID = @GroupID AND Position < @Position
        select @str = RTRIM(dbo.GetPrefixTo(@GroupID, @beforePosition, substring(@String, 1, @Position))) + 
            + RTrim(Value) + substring(@String, @Position + 1, len(@string) + 1)
        FROM Chars WHERE GroupID = @GroupID AND Position = @Position
    END
    ELSE
        SELECT @str = substring(@String, 1, @Position) + RTrim(Value) + substring(@String, @Position + 1, len(@string) + 1) FROM Chars
        WHERE GroupID = @GroupID AND Position = @Position
    RETURN @str
END
```

---

And group by GroupID and aggregate max(position):

```
SELECT groupID, max(Position)
    , dbo.GetPrefixTo(groupID, max(Position), 'abcde') 
    FROM Chars 
    GROUP BY GroupID
```

---

This is the result:

```
1           0           Xabcde                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2           2           abYcde                                                                                                                                                                                                  
3           5           abcdeZ                                                                                                                                                                                                  
4           2           XabYcde                                                                                                                                                                                                 
5           5           abYcdeZ                                                                                                                                                                                                 
6           5           XabcdeZ                                                                                                                                                                                                 
7           5           XabYcdeZ                                                                                                                                                                                                
8           4           abY1cdY2e                                                                                                                                                                                               
9           4           XabY1cdY2e                                                                                                                                                                                              
10          5           abY1cdY2eZ                                                                                                                                                                                              
11          5           XabY1cdY2eZ
```

========================================================================